# C# Socket - How do I keep socket open?

Tags: c#, loops, stream

I have this code. I can receive data from my client successfully, but only one time. After I receive the data once, if the client attempts to send any more the server isn't receiving it. Can anyone help?

```
    private void startListening()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;


        try
        {

            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7079);

            server.Start();

            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            //Enter listening loop
            while (true)
            {

                addLog("Waiting for push.");

                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                addLog("Push request received, accepted.");

                data = null;

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                //Loop to receive all data
                while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0)
                {
                    //Translate data bytes to ASCII string
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                    //Process data
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    //send response
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    addLog("Received: '" + data + "'");
                }

                //End ALL Connections
                client.Close();
                server.Stop();
            }
        }
        catch(SocketException e)
        {
            addLog("SocketException: " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Stop listening for new clients
            MessageBox.Show("Finished.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Protecting your product! What about sharing knowledge ? What about saving @Karl-Johan Sjögren time he might wasted answering your question ?

Comment: a) Your original code is still visible by clicking the "edited" link. b) All user-generated content on StackOverflow is licensed under a Creative Commons license. c) In cases like these, it is advisable to create a minimum reproducible example- that is, remove any part of the code that is not relevant to the problem, make sure the problem still happens, and then post that code.

Comment: Sorry, you're both right. I re-added the code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are closing both the server and the client in the end of your loop (`server.Stop();`). Your outer loop will keep going and try to get a new TcpClient from your server (which would mean a new connection is made) but since you've already stopped the server then that will never happen (or probably throw an exception).

Comment: Ah thanks, I had to remove `server.Stop()` as well as modify one thing in my client's code. Thanks for the tip!